# Logrotate Timing?

Tags: logs, logrotate

I've configured logrotation and it works the way I want it to when I force the update. I'm using the filesize condition as you can see in the config below, but I'm wondering how often this condition is checked? Will the rotate occur instantly when my file reaches 3GB in size, or will it sit at 3GB until the next timing interval which is...?

I'd like to make it as close to instantaneous as possible :)

```
----@----------:/var/log/upstart# vim /etc/logrotate.d/upstart

/var/log/upstart/*-server.log.* {
        size 3G
        missingok
        rotate 5
        compress
        notifempty
        nocreate
}

    root@osshonisyslog1s:/var/log/upstart# vim  /etc/crontab

# /etc/crontab: system-wide crontab
# Unlike any other crontab you don't have to run the `crontab'
# command to install the new version when you edit this file
# and files in /etc/cron.d. These files also have username fields,
# that none of the other crontabs do.

SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
*/5 * * * * /etc/cron.daily/logrotate
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, as soon as the script finds the file is above 3G it will go ahead with the compress and rotate the file as configured.